# What type should I use for a React component with arbitrary properties?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to use a component like:

```
<toolProperties.ToolElement
                        onGenerate={onGenerate}
                        postData={postData}
                        status={status}
                        setStatus={setStatus}
                        setToolOutputs={setToolOutputs} />
```

I have `toolProperties` typed with:

```
interface IToolProperties {
    toolName: string;
    title: string;
    description: string;
    ToolElement: React.ComponentType
}
```

It gives a type error: `Type '({ status, setStatus, setToolOutputs, onGenerate, postData }: IToolProps) => Element' is not assignable to type 'ComponentType<{}>'`

Is there a better way to type it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make `IToolProperties` generic as well, e.g.:

```
interface IToolProperties<T> {
    toolName: string;
    title: string;
    description: string;
    ToolElement: React.ComponentType<T>
}
```

Then when you have a specific use for this interface, provide the props interface of your `ToolElement`:

```
const nameTools: IToolsProperties<{name: string}>
```

And then this could be used like this:

```
<nameTools.ToolElement name="foo" />
```

Comment: I get `Cannot find name 'T'.ts`